# How to store a json value in a postgres column

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table with two columns,One column should store **int**  and other should store **json**.

here the data which i want to store in the table.

```
id,polygon
1,"{""type"": ""Feature"",
    ""properties"": {
        ""stroke"": ""#555555"",
        ""stroke-width"": 2,
        ""stroke-opacity"": 1,
        ""fill"": ""#00aa22"",
        ""fill-opacity"": 0.5
    },
    ""geometry"": {
        ""type"": ""Polygon"",
        ""coordinates"": [
            [
                [-76.97021484375,
                    40.17887331434696
                ],
                [-74.02587890625,
                    39.842286020743394
                ],
                [-73.4326171875,
                    41.713930073371294
                ],
                [-76.79443359375,
                    41.94314874732696
                ],
                [-76.97021484375,
                    40.17887331434696
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}"
```

I tired storing in postgres as follows:

```
insert into gjl_polygon values(1,'"{""type"": 
""Feature"",""properties"": {""stroke"": ""#555555"",""stroke- 
width"": 2,""stroke-opacity"": 1,""fill"": ""#00aa22"",""fill- 
opacity"": 0.5},""geometry"": {""type"": 
""Polygon"",""coordinates"": 
[[[-76.97021484375,40.17887331434696],[-74.02587890625, 
39.842286020743394 ],[-73.4326171875, 41.713930073371294], 
[-76.79443359375,41.94314874732696], 
[-76.97021484375,40.17887331434696]]]}}"');
```

I got the following error,

```
Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 4 (char 3)
```

Comment: It looks like you have a string wrapped in a string `'"{""type"": 
""Feature"",...` this should probably look more like `'{"type":"feature",...` without the extra double quotes `"`

Comment: Trying to remove extra double quotes get me the following error                                                                            **Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 4 (char 3)**

Comment: Hmm, that's the same error you originally mentioned

Comment: Is that an actual query you are executing? Including new lines in places that shouldn't have them? Did you remove double quotes from start and end of your string (those are not double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is the use of double quotes twice. Try to edit like this:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "stroke": "#555555",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "fill": "#00aa22",
        "fill-opacity": 0.5
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [-76.97021484375,
                    40.17887331434696
                ],
                [-74.02587890625,
                    39.842286020743394
                ],
                [-73.4326171875,
                    41.713930073371294
                ],
                [-76.79443359375,
                    41.94314874732696
                ],
                [-76.97021484375,
                    40.17887331434696
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

The JSON above is a valid JSON string and it should work as expected.